# error expected initializer before < token

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, operator-keyword

I am overloading the assignment operator, and am getting this error. Cannot solve it.

Here is the prototype inside template  class binTree

```
binTree <T>& operator = ( const binTree <T>& ); // assignment operator
```

Here is the method

```
// assignment operator
template <class T>
void binTree <T>::binTree <T>& operator = ( const binTree <T>& p)
{
    if( this != &p ) 
    { 
        clear(root); // clear tree 
        root = copy(p.root); // copy tree
    }      
    return *this;
}
```

I am getting the error on this line

```
void binTree <T>::binTree <T>& operator = ( const binTree <T>& p)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your declaration

```
binTree <T>& operator = ( const binTree <T>& );
```

Your class type is

```
binTree<T>::
```

your member is

```
operator =(const BinTree<T>& p)
```

Your return type is

```
binTree<T>&
```

So your definition is

```
binTree<T>& binTree<T>::operator= (const binTree<T>& p){
     // bug-free code goes here
}
```

Comment: @user1236803 You are most welcome. You can mark questions as solved by checking the checkmark next to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the second `bintree<T>` in the return type

```
binTree <T>& operator = ( const binTree <T>& p)
```

EDIT: removed `void` from beginning of line (the result of too fast copy-paste)

Comment: you are right, you don't need the `void` either -- hasty copy-paste... (corrected)